# bar file deployment on windows

Tags: ant, messagebroker

I am creating a new target to deploy bar on Windows, earlier it was on Unix box. However my target is not deploying anything. Build is successful but no deployment.

Unix Target

```
<target depends="" description="Deploys to the selected MQSI broker." name="MQSI-cvs-deploy-broker">
    <echo message="Deploying to MQSI broker using broker.properties file..."/>
    <echo/>
    <echo message="Broker: ${release.broker.name}"/>
    <echo/>
    <property file="${release.working.dir}/${product.code}/broker.properties"/>
    <echo message ="${release.working.dir}/${product.code}/broker.properties"/>

    <propertycopy name="release.execgroup.names" from="${environment.code}.execgroup.names"/>
    <foreach list="${release.execgroup.names}" inheritall="true" target="MQSI-cvs-deploy-execgroup" param="release.execgroup.name"/>
</target>

<target depends="" description="Deploys to the selected MQSI execution groups." name="MQSI-cvs-deploy-execgroup">
    <echo message="Deploying to MQSI broker's execution group..."/>
    <echo/>
    <echo message="Execgroup: ${release.execgroup.name}"/>
    <echo/> <if>
        <equals arg1="${product.code}" arg2="MQSIWebSvcs"/>
        <then>
            <ssh username="${server.deploy.username}" password="${server.deploy.password}" host="${server.host.ip}" verifyhost="false">
                  <shell>
                <write>cd ${updated.server.deploy.dir}</write>
                <write>echo "Removing existing ${product.code} flows from ${environment.code} broker on ${DSTAMP}_${TSTAMP}" >> DeployHistory/History.txt</write>
                <write>mqsideploy ${release.broker.name} -e ${release.execgroup.name} -d src.FTT_WebSvc_Request:src.FTT_WebSvc_HttpRequest:src.FTT_WebSvc_Response -w 90</write>
                <write>echo done</write>
                <read>done</read>
                   </shell> 
            </ssh>
        </then>
    </if>
    <echo/>

    <exec username="${server.deploy.username}" password="${server.deploy.password}" host="${server.deploy.machine}" verifyhost="false">
           <shell>
        <write>cd ${updated.server.deploy.dir}</write>
        <write>echo "Deploying ${release.bar.file} to ${environment.code} broker on ${DSTAMP}_${TSTAMP}" >> DeployHistory/History.txt</write>
        <write>mqsideploy ${release.broker.name} -e ${release.execgroup.name} -a ${release.bar.file} -w 90</write>
        <write>echo done</write>
        <read>done</read>
           </shell>
    </exec>
```

Here is My Windows code

```
<target depends="" description="Deploys to the selected MQSI execution groups." name="MQSI-cvs-deploy-execgroup_QA">
    <echo message="Deploying to MQSI broker's execution group..."/>
    <echo/>
    <echo message="Execgroup: ${release.execgroup.name}"/>
    <attribue username="${mqsiqa.server.deploy.username}" password="${mqsiqa.server.deploy.password}" host="10.202.79.39" verifyhost="false" >

    </attribue>

    <exec dir="C:\Program Files\IBM\MQSI\9.0.0.3\bin" executable="cmd.exe"  failonerror="true">
                <arg line="mqsideploy"/>
                <arg value="-n" />
                <arg value="${release.broker.name}" />
                <arg value="-e" />
                <arg value="${release.execgroup.name}" />
                <arg value="-a" />
                <arg value="${release.bar.file}" />
                <arg value="-w" />
                <arg value="90" />
            </exec>

</target>
```

Don't know, where going wrong.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The UNIX target seems to be executing mqsideploy on a remote host, while the Windows target seems to be local. And I don't think it will even work locally. If you only set the BAR filename in the ${release.bar.file} variable, mqsideploy will not have the full path of the BAR. Is there another target for copying the BAR?

Comment: yes..I have added the tag.